# Bayesian inference iteration

Tags: bayesian

[1]. Prior ⇒ Data ⇒ Posterior [Prior] ⇒ More Data ⇒ Posterior

[2]. Prior ⇒ All Data ⇒ Posterior

What is the difference of waiting for the full data set compared to updating the prior as new data becomes available?

Do we get the same posterior distribution?

Comment: Yes, as you can check by writing the posterior update sequentially versus all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xi'an said, updating is quite natural.
After the first sample, $y^{(1)}$, we have
$$\pi(\theta|y^{(1)}) \propto f(y^{(1)}|\theta) \pi(\theta) $$

Sampling (independently) another data set $y^{(2)}$ yields
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi(\theta|y^{(1)},y^{(2)}) &\propto& f(y^{(1)},y^{(2)}|\theta) \pi(\theta) \notag\\
&\propto&f(y^{(2)}|y^{(1)},\theta) f(y^{(1)}|\theta) \pi(\theta) \notag\\
&\propto&f(y^{(2)}|y^{(1)},\theta) \pi(\theta|y^{(1)}) \notag\\
&\propto&f(y^{(2)}|\theta) \pi(\theta|y^{(1)}) \label{updatedprior}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, the posterior of the first sample becomes the prior for the updated sample.

In this way, we update the prior as new information becomes available.

Comment: Thank you Chris!